# Make a camera app compatible with VR headset

Tags: android, virtual-reality, stereoscopy

I'm new with the Google VR SDK and I'm wondering what would you advise me to use in this case : I've an Android camera application (taking and viewing pictures with optional filters) that I need to make compatible with VR headset for smartphones.

Can I display the same picture/camera view twice on the screen or do I need to take 2 different pictures to make a stereoscopic image? If so how should I do?

Comment: Did you get any answer to your question?

Comment: I didn't. I tried some tutorials to use the Google VR SDK but the result was not concluant (not fluid enough) and I gave up. I hope it'll be easier in the future ;)